# Grip shifters not opening on a Mongoose Terrex (trying to remove the shifting cable)

Tags: mountain-bike, grip-shifter

I'm trying replace the shifting cable on my mountain bike. The bike has grip shifts. I loosened the hex screw on the grip shift and was able to slide the grip part off the shift housing but it doesn't expose the shifting cable. Then I was able to remove a piece of the housing which exposed the cable but am still not able to reach the end of the cable to remove it.

If I put any more force, I'm just gonna break it. There's something I'm missing. It can't be that tight and there aren't any holes left to tinker with, lol.

Any help or ideas to access the cable would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you loosened that grub screw next to your thumb? It's prolly 2.5mm hex. Loosen that and that aspect of the shifter should come free.

Comment: Ya that's the first thing I did. I thought it would come right off once the grub screw is loosened. But it didn't. I had a breakthrough though, you see that curved part right next to my thumb, I got that off. The mechanism is similar to Shimano Revoshift shifters. I can see the cable inside the housing now, but still not able to access the end of the cable to remove it.

Comment: If you push the cable backwards through the shifter, the head often comes out through a hole in the shifter, though I haven't used that specific design. having that cover plate off helps when you thread the new one through

Comment: @Swifty I've been trying to push the cable through for a while now but the head isn't popping out. The cable is beginning to lose its thread and its getting harder to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need help, or someone else needs this, I just got one open. Take it off the bar. Take out the grub screw and separate the silver ring it goes in from the body. Looking down the hole from where the ring was, you’ll see locking fins (?) that hold the body together. You can use a screw driver to pop the fins off from the inside and it all comes apart.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

Leave it on the Handlebar. Move the Brake lever 1" - 2cm away. Loosen grub screw and move the gear changer up beside the brake lever. You should have a gap on the bar - to the hand Grip. Move the Grip shift to *6 or *1 for main rings.

Remove the small Curved Cable cover as per your picture above.  Insert a 4-5mm flat 3/16 screwdriver at the Tab - mid point of the small cover.

Push the tip of the screwdriver in to touch the Handle bar, then LEVER the rotating section off toward the Bar end.  It may take some Force to pop it off. Separate the parts slowly and observe positions of A LARGE Spring, the BENT Spring & Cable end. Set the selector at *6 for reassembly.

Good Luck.